# TextBlock that overlays the container it's in

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got an `ItemsControl` that dynamically builds a grid of sorts, with the cells being a relatively simple custom control with a single line of text (`TextBlock`), and optionally some colours applied.

Now I was given the task to "merge" the text on cells with the same properties.

In other words - when the conditions are right (binding controlled) I'd like to have a `TextBlock` contained inside an `ItemsControl` overlay its own container.

[image]

Is this even possible? I thought I saw things "overflow" other things in WPF, but I'm not sure how to control this at will, especially when an `ItemsControl` is in use.

Note that I cannot actually "merge" these same cells into a single "wider" cell because each element must still be clickable.

Comment: You can set minus value to the padding of ContentControl or the margin of content to make the content to overflow.

Comment: @emoacht Perfect! Feel free to make this into an answer and I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes setting minus value to the padding or margin is useful when you want to make a child go beyond its parent.

```xml
<Button Width="160" Height="80" Padding="-1000,0">
    <TextBlock FontSize="24"
               Text="Text that can overlay the Button it's in"/>
</Button>
```

[image: example]